# How and What to mention 'ON' while joining tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT D1.DISTRICT_NAME, E1.EMP_FNAME, E1.EMP_LNAME, T1.TAX_YEAR, T1.DATE_LAST_CALC

FROM DISTRICT D1

JOIN EMPLOYEE E1 ON ????s
JOIN TOTAL PAB T1 ON ????s
```

I need to use a join operator but I don't know how to use it or what to put where I have the ????s. And do I need to make 2 other from statements for the other ones like TOTAL_PAB and EMPLOYEE? Thanks

Comment: post up tables and some sample data

Comment: are you asking how do you determine the foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look something like this

```
SELECT D1.DISTRICT_NAME, E1.EMP_FNAME, E1.EMP_LNAME, T1.TAX_YEAR, T1.DATE_LAST_CALC

FROM DISTRICT D1

JOIN EMPLOYEE E1 ON D1.PrimarKey = E1.ForeignKey
JOIN TOTAL PAB T1 ON D1|E1.PrimaryKey=T1.ForeignKey
```

You pick Primary Key from one table and join it with Foreignkey of the other. You can also join on no-primary keys but that will give you a lot of duplicates which won't want.

Comment: Do I need to make 3 separate JOIN ON statements since I'm using 3 different tables

Comment: probably 2 joins.....The number of join conditions is (n-1), if there are more than two tables joined in a query where 'n' is the number of tables involved. The rule must be true to avoid Cartesian product.  perhaps this would be useful   http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm

Comment: @barryrobinholt 2 joins are need to join 3 tables. `A JOIN B JOIN C`